# Print logs on Android source code using Eclipse breakpoints?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

In a debug effort to understand what the system is doing I would like to use the java debugger *conditional breakpoints* mechanism to print log messages on specific lines in Android's source code.

How would I do it? I don't exactly know, that's this question all about.

Things I do know:
The Eclipse java debugger has *"conditional Breakpoints"*, i.e., you set a breakpoint in the code and you write a condition. Each time the code reaches the breakpoint line it will stop execution only if the condition you wrote is `true`, otherwise it will not stop.

I though that maybe this mechanism can be twisted to print a log message at a specific line in the code instead of stopping the execution. And if it can be done I could be able to track what Android's source code is doing.

Comment: I don't get the question, please improve.

Comment: @Warpzit I rewrote it. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression in a conditional breakpoint:

```
android.util.Log.v("MyApp", "my message") == -1
```

This will make your breakpoints not break the execution and in the LogCat View, filtering the view using the `tag:MyApp` expression, you will get the desired logged messages. You can also use other log levels (`a`, `i`, `e`, `w`). See the Log [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for more info.

To have the breakpoint always break, use:

```
android.util.Log.v("MyApp", "my message") >= 0
```

The return value of `Log.v` is the number of bytes the log message internally has, so it will always a positive number.

**ADDENDUM**:
There is a more elegant way to do it. Eclipse conditional breakpoints can be any java code, including using local variables at the breakpoint. The last return value must be `true` if you actually want to stop execution or `false`. So the same can be achieved as:

```
android.util.Log.v("MyApp", "my message");
return false;
```

or you can make more complicated statements like:

```
if( t.isNumber() ) {
    System.out.println("A number found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a number");
    return true; // stops execution
}
android.util.Log.v("MyApp", "my message");
return false; // does not stop execution
```

Comment: Maybe you know also why the breakpoint condition does not recognize my package name? I wrote `(com.example.test.MyClass.stop == 2)`, `stop` being a `public static int` of MyClass. Eclipse tells me **Conditional breakpoint has compilation errors. Reason: com.example cannot be resolved to a variable**

Comment: I've seen that but I never got that annoyed to also find a solution. One explanation is this: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F In my case I always worked around the expresion or used other debugging techniques.